# Expression evaluation order

Tags: c++

I recently got confused by the following c++ snippet:

```
#include <cstdio>

int lol(int *k){
  *k +=5;
   return *k;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){
  int k = 0;
  int w = k + lol(&k);
  printf("%d\n", w);
  return 0;
}
```

Take a look at line:

```
int w = k + lol(&k);
```

Until now I thought that this expression would be evaluated from left to right: take current value of k (which before calll to lol function is 0) and then add it to the result of lol function. But compiler proves me I'm wrong, the value of w is 10. Even if I switch places to make it

```
int w = lol(&k) + k;
```

the result would be still 10. What am I doing wrong?

Tomek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the parameters in an expression are ***not*** specified to be evaluated in any particular order.

The compiler is free to execute either parameter `k` or `lol(&k)` first. There are no sequence points in that expression. **This means that the side-effects of the parameters can be executed in any order.**

So in short, it's not specified whether the code prints `5` or `10`. Both are valid outputs.

The exception to this is short-circuiting in boolean expressions because `&&` and `||` are sequence points. (see comments)

Comment: `&&`, `||` and `?:`, which appear in expressions, are sequence points.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Thanks for that bit of info. I wasn't sure on the exact language semantecs that made boolean expressions different. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Note that only the built-in `&&` and `||` (and also `,`) are sequence points. If they are overloaded, then they become two-argument functions, and function arguments' evaluation order is unspecified.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: You're right, "undefined behavior" is the wrong word to use in this case. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't realized that other operations weren't sequence points, but this makes good sense because otherwise you'd lose too many optimizations.  && and || otoh always optimize like flow control.

Answer (score 3):

This code either yields 5 or 10 depending on the choice of evaluation oder of the function call relative to that of the left side of +.

Its behavior is *not* undefined because a function call is surrounded by two sequence points.

Answer (score 2):

`Plus` is by definition commutative, so the order in your example is totally implementation-defined.

**Mysticial** is right when mentioning sequence points. Citing [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) (don't have C++ standard at hand):

> A sequence point in imperative programming defines any point in a
>   computer program's execution at which it is guaranteed that all side
>   effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side
>   effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed. They are
>   often mentioned in reference to C and C++, because the result of some
>   expressions can depend on the order of evaluation of their
>   subexpressions. Adding one or more sequence points is one method of
>   ensuring a consistent result, because this restricts the possible
>   orders of evaluation.

The article also has a list of sequence point in C++.

Comment: "_your example is totally implementation-defined._" No, it isn't. No implementation that I know of define what happens.

Comment: @curiousguy: Perhaps, I didn't make myself clear. Should I have said "implementation-specific" or "compiler-specific"?

Comment: or "implementation dependant", or just "unspecified".